# How to get previous/next week number and year in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, date, datetime, week-number

I have this Week based navigation in the UI and on click on the left/right arrows I was calling an API and returning the data with previous week/year number and next week/year number but now I need to handle it in ASP.NET Core 6. So it was working fine using PHP with API. The PHP code is given below with request and output.

[image]

The below code of PHP is working as expected. But I need same output in APS.NET Core 6.

```
$prev_week = date ("W", strtotime ($year. 'W' . $week . ' -1 week'));
$prev_year = date ("o", strtotime ($year. 'W' . $week . ' -1 week'));
$next_week = date ("W", strtotime ($year. 'W' . $week . ' +1 week'));
$next_year = date ("o", strtotime ($year. 'W' . $week . ' +1 week'));
```

If I have week as 52 and Year 2023 then the output of this code will be :

```
prev_week 51
prev_year 2023
next_week 01
next_year 2024
```

Now I am trying to convert the above code into ASP.NET Core 6 but I am not able to get the exact output as PHP. Here is what I did till now.

As I have already Year and Week number so I just wanted to get the previous and Next week and if its year end or first week of year then the previous week and year should say week as 1 and Year should be previous year.

```
using System;

int prev_week = DateTime.ParseExact($"{year}-W{week}", "yyyy-'W'w", null).AddWeeks(-1).Week;
int prev_year = DateTime.ParseExact($"{year}-W{week}", "yyyy-'W'w", null).AddWeeks(-1).Year;
int next_week = DateTime.ParseExact($"{year}-W{week}", "yyyy-'W'w", null).AddWeeks(1).Week;
int next_year = DateTime.ParseExact($"{year}-W{week}", "yyyy-'W'w", null).AddWeeks(1).Year;
```

this code is not giving me same result.

I would like to get the same output as shown above as getting from php using viewmodel in asp.net core 6 web api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could use [nodatime package](https://nodatime.org/) and try to use below codes:

You could install by using below nuget package command.

Install-Package NodaTime

You could create a model class:

```
public class WeekYearInfo
{
    public int PrevWeek { get; set; }
    public int PrevYear { get; set; }
    public int NextWeek { get; set; }
    public int NextYear { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could create a calculate method:

```
    public static WeekYearInfo CalculatePrevNextWeekYear(int year, int week)
   {
       LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.FromWeekYearWeekAndDay(year, week, IsoDayOfWeek.Monday);
       LocalDate prevWeekDate = inputDate.PlusWeeks(-1);
       LocalDate nextWeekDate = inputDate.PlusWeeks(1);
       IWeekYearRule rule = WeekYearRules.Iso;

       return new WeekYearInfo
       {
           PrevWeek = rule.GetWeekOfWeekYear(prevWeekDate),
           PrevYear = rule.GetWeekYear(prevWeekDate),
           NextWeek = rule.GetWeekOfWeekYear(nextWeekDate),
           NextYear = rule.GetWeekYear(nextWeekDate)
       };
   }
```

At last, you could call it inside the controller:

```
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        int year = 2023;
        int week = 52;
        WeekYearInfo result = CalculatePrevNextWeekYear(year, week);

        return View(result);
    }
```

Result:

[image]

---

Edit:

```
    public static WeekYearInfo CalculatePrevNextWeekYear(int year, int week)
    {


        DateTime firstDayOfYear = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
        int daysOffset = DayOfWeek.Thursday - firstDayOfYear.DayOfWeek;
        DateTime firstThursday = firstDayOfYear.AddDays(daysOffset);
        var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
        int firstWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(firstThursday, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);

        DateTime targetDate = firstDayOfYear.AddDays(week * 7 - (firstWeek == 1 ? 0 : 7));
        DateTime prevWeekDate = firstDayOfYear.AddDays(-7);
        DateTime nextWeekDate = firstDayOfYear.AddDays(7);

        return new WeekYearInfo
        {
            PrevWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(prevWeekDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday),
            PrevYear = prevWeekDate.Year,
            NextWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(nextWeekDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday),
            NextYear = nextWeekDate.Year
        };
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Brando Zhang thanks for the solution but I need to make this working without installing any extra package. So can't be this done without that in ASP.NET Core 6.0. ?

Comment: It possible, you could try my update codes.